# Detect number of line in UITextView ( iPhone 6 plus failed)

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I use this code :

```
numOfLine = (textView.contentSize.height -   lineHeightFix ) / textView.font.lineHeight;
```

In iphone 4,5,5s,6 this line works grate but in iPhone 6 plus its return a  incorrect line number.

I also tried this code:

```
float rows = (textView.contentSize.height - textView.textContainerInset.top - textView.textContainerInset.bottom) / textView.font.lineHeight;
```

But I will stay with the same problem.

Comment: Can you give the value of each field and the total result ? And can you try to cast the whole ie: float rows=(float)(textView...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this with this code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

CGRect previousRect = CGRectZero;

}



- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:  (NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
 if (currentRect.origin.y >= previousRect.origin.y)
{
  // Counts the lines    
}
previousRect = currentRect;
```